# Using MutationObserver with IE9 compatibility in IE11 browser

Tags: internet-explorer, mutation-observers

In our project, we are using IE11 with the IE9 meta tag. Because of which I am getting the error `'MutationObserver' is undefined`.
I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way we can use IE11 supported components with IE9 meta tag?
2. Is there any alternative similar to MutationObserver for IE9 which I can use with minimum changes in my code and source repo?

Really appreciate your help and support!!

Comment: No. You're telling IE to emulate IE9 (which means no `MutationObserver`). If you want to use newer standards, stop telling IE to emulate an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IE11, and don't need to support IE9, there is no good reason to have the compatibility meta tag. As you have seen, it disables all kinds of useful stuff.

That said, if you need to actually support IE9, or really need the meta tag (which is terrible), you can use a polyfill. https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/master/src/MutationObserver/MutationObserver.js